# How can exactly create a view of the exterior in 360o of an object?

Tags: php, html, node.js, reactjs, react-native

first off all

i am trying to code a 360 view of an object **(like a Walkaround - only exterior)**,
just like the example below:
https://spins.spincar.com/spincarcomdemo/wp0ab2a70jl135405

Currently my software stack is:

```
PHP
Node.js
React
React Native
```

And i have tried to search ways to make that, but it seems that it does not appear anywhere.

I already know how to render panoramic photos (i mean 360 photos).

But i just wanna know **Step by Step** how can that be make from a video.

because the example URL. it is like a video, but the dragging feature
relies on some frames took from the video and saved as an image.

> If you visit the example URL, you will understand.

so exactly i would love to know how can that be made.

**Thanks for reading**

Comment: [like that?](https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video consist of multiple image frame. If your take a video of you walking around the car and play it back it look like you show 360 view of an object.

Here is sample from your example:
https://cdn.spincar.com/swipetospin-viewers/spincarcomdemo/wp0ab2a70jl135405/20190222192724.K4BAQSBW/ec/0-0.jpg

They have 60 frame like that from 0-0 to 0-60. The algorithm I think of is: having a video you cut into frames. them have a slider to play them back. Or implement a drag feature, drag left decrease frame, drag right increase frame, remember to wrap around

```
currentFrame = (currentFrame + dragDirection) % totalFrame
```

```js
const $slider = document.getElementById('frame');
const $img = document.getElementById('img');
$slider.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  $img.src = `https://cdn.spincar.com/swipetospin-viewers/spincarcomdemo/wp0ab2a70jl135405/20190222192724.K4BAQSBW/ec/0-${e.target.value}.jpg`;
});

// Preload your imgs
for (let i = 0; i <= 63; i ++) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = `https://cdn.spincar.com/swipetospin-viewers/spincarcomdemo/wp0ab2a70jl135405/20190222192724.K4BAQSBW/ec/0-${i}.jpg`
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.spincar.com/swipetospin-viewers/spincarcomdemo/wp0ab2a70jl135405/20190222192724.K4BAQSBW/ec/0-0.jpg" alt="Car" id="img" />

<input type="range" id="frame" name="frame" min="0" max="63" value="0">
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough buddy!
It will help me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Reverse engineer is your friend :D